# The "installing ubuntu alongside with windows" option

Tags: system-installation

I'm new to Linux and faced a problem which is really serious for me.

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 ISO file and used Unetbootin to make a usb stick. I had installed Windows 8 that moment, unfortunately I couldn't install Ubuntu alongside Win8 so I ***erased my disk*** and installed Windows 7. Sadly I can't have "installing Ubuntu alongside with windows " option now too. I tried other version of Linux or even Ubuntu 13.04, but still the answer was NO.

I have:
Asus K55v 6G RAm, 750G HDD, core i7.

My disk is MBR with:

```
1)100 Mb System reserve 

2)C:126G primary 

3)D:244G Logical 

4)E:284G Logical 

5)43G Unallocated
```

I can't install Ubuntu manually because it can't see my partitions or Unallocated space,it just sees my whole hard disk entirely, I tried it and it erased whole of my hard disk.

***I don't want to use Wubi.*** BTW all that I was talking Here was about _64 bit OSes.
Few month ago I had no problem of installing win7 and Ubuntu alongside!

I'm getting worry about maybe my laptop has physical or some kind of problem.
[image]

Comment: Can you boot from LiveCD, and add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Upload an image, add the link, and I'll add it for you.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/35hnvgp/5

Comment: Wow, I think I'm gonna love this askubuntu site. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to "test Ubuntu" option via the live cd and then installing Ubuntu via the live cd?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work out.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339455/bought-a-new-wd-1tb-elements-usb3-i-wanted-to-install-xubuntu-12-04-in-it-but-i You appear to have the same problem